# Tensorflow GPU not working on Ubuntu 20.04 (error message)

Tags: installation, python, gpu, ubuntu-20.04, cuda

So, I tried to go through several tutorials (the latest being [this one](https://heads0rtai1s.github.io/2021/02/25/gpu-setup-r-python-ubuntu/)) to set up GPU support for TensorFlow on Ubuntu 20.04 and I always get the following message:

```
joris@joris-N751JK:~$ python3.9
Python 3.9.10 (main, Jan 15 2022, 18:17:56) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
2022-02-25 00:13:21.489977: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:936] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-02-25 00:13:21.628965: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:936] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-02-25 00:13:21.629374: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:936] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

What does it mean and how to solve it?

Comment: Do you have a [GPU on the device that is CUDA certified / able to run CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus)? (on top of following the guide - installing CUDA drivers and CUDNN and all that). Also some more reading about related issues (and has answer) on it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44232898/memoryerror-in-tensorflow-and-successful-numa-node-read-from-sysfs-had-negativ

Comment: Yes, I have GeForce GTX 850M